# What is the difference between delta (Δ) R² and adjusted R²?

Tags: terminology

Is delta (Δ) R² the same as adjusted R² ?

I have delta R² in my notes somewhere and it didn't come up on a Google Search.

Comment: I just found great notes on the subject here:
http://www.bwgriffin.com/gsu/courses/edur8132/video/delta_r_squared/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delta R2 is the change in R2 between two equations. Usually you see this come up when doing hierarchical regression with more than one step. For example, Step 1 R2 = .25 and Step 2 deltaR2 = .10. This would mean that Step 2 added .10 beyond the .25 of step 1, for a total of R2 = .35.

Edit: I should also mention that the deltaR2 will be associated with its own F value. This value will indicate whether the increase in R2 (deltaR2) is statistically significantly greater than no increase.